# Mocking - Adding items into a DynamoDB table

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, mocking, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to test the functionality of adding items into a DynamoDB table using a unit test in C#. Is it possible to test it using mock ups without actually adding it to the table?

At the moment my test is failing when I'm loading the table throwing the following exception `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Is it possible to mock up the table?

Comment: Have you considered dry-run api calls?

Comment: No, but I'm going to look into this now. Thanks, @TomNijs

Comment: I'd be interested if you get anything working. The only good option I am aware of is to spin up a local dynamodb instance and actually make the calls to that. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html